# VBA; When dimensioning 2 module classes in one line, I get a ByRef error. But splitting them to two lines works

Tags: excel, vba

With the following, the compiler gives a ByRef error in `ttt()` line 5 --> argument `Data` gets highlighted

```vbs
Option Explicit

Sub ttt()
    Dim s As String: s = "M1"
    Dim Data, Data2 As c_dict_Project
    Set Data = GetMyData(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test"), s)
    Set Data2 = GetMyData(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test"), s)
    If SetClass(Data, s) Then Debug.Print "Done"
End Sub

Public Function GetMyData(ByVal wsO As Worksheet, newMod As String) As c_dict_Project
    Dim project As c_dict_Project: Set project = New c_dict_Project
    Set project.Modules = New Scripting.Dictionary
    project.Modules.Add newMod, "My Content"
    'project.Modules.Add "M2", wsO.Cells(1,1).Text
    Set GetMyData = project
End Function

Public Function SetClass(ByRef Data As c_dict_Project, module As String) As Boolean
    Debug.Print Data.Modules(module)
    SetClass = True
End Function
```

However, the error disperses if I change `ttt()` line 2

From:

```vbs
Dim Data, Data2 As c_dict_Project
```

To:

```vbs
Dim Data As c_dict_Project
Dim Data2 As c_dict_Project
```

Is this some sort of Excel VBA bug, or is there a reason why I can't dimension 2 module classes in one single statement

Comment: `Data` is being defined as a `Variant` then... Dim doesnt work like you think it does... you have to do it like this: `Dim Data As c_dict_Project, Data2 As c_dict_Project` --- what you have actually means `Dim Data As Variant, Data2 As c_dict_Project`

Comment: ok, I always tough that all variables listed in a row gets the same format as given by the last value. However,  you are absolutely correct. I set a break point and could in fact see in the watch window that `Data` was declared as a Variant. Thank you

Comment: you are not the first person to think that - everyone who is new to vba thinks that too

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Dim Data, Data2 As c_dict_Project
```

declares the `Data` variable as a Variant.

> Multiple declarations on a single line. `AnotherVar` is of type **Variant** because its type is omitted.
>
> `Dim AnotherVar, Choice As Boolean, BirthDate As Date`

This line:

```
 If SetClass(Data, s) Then Debug.Print "Done"
```

then calls the `SetClass` function:

> Public Function SetClass(ByRef Data As c_dict_Project, module As String) As Boolean

`Data` is being passed by reference (you don't need to state this as it is the default), and if you pass by reference **and** declare the data type, then they must be an exact match. If you don't declare the data type in a procedure, the default is **Variant**, and you must pass a **Variant**.

> An argument passed **ByRef** (by reference), the default, must have the precise data type expected in the procedure.

Although `Data` now holds a `c_dict_Project` type object, from:

```
Public Function GetMyData(ByVal wsO As Worksheet, newMod As String) As c_dict_Project
```

it is still treated as a Variant, and so is not an exact type match.

Ref:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/byref-argument-type-mismatch